# SDL2, C++, MinGW64: undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, sdl-2

I've been trying to set up SDL2 with MinGW, but I've encountered this error repeatedly:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

I have tried adding `#define SDL_HANDLED_MAIN` to the top of main.cpp, and it does work, however I would like to know how I could get this running using SDL's system, and not bypassing it.

Linkers (in order):  -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image

Code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **)
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The linked post addresses this, in the "undefined reference to WinMain only" section. Unrelated to the question, you should update your compiler, GCC 6 is five years old...

Comment: This question should help with that: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-to-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2)

Comment: This might be helpful: [I get "Undefined reference to 'WinMain@16'"](https://wiki.libsdl.org/FAQWindows#i_get_undefined_reference_to_winmain16)